# What is Open Web Interface for .Net?

Tags: owin, katana

I searched the web more trying to know what is OWIN (Open Web Interface for .Net). I got more information that it decouples server and application, but I am still confused and I can't understand it well.

Comment: I came across this question and was surprised that there were not enough answers despite the question being considered valid (i.e. not yet closed :)) - There is another question on SO which is appropriately answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524060/how-to-explain-katana-and-owin-in-simple-words-and-uses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain Katana and OWIN in simple words and uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524060/how-to-explain-katana-and-owin-in-simple-words-and-uses)